# How to flatten rows into columns and specify column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have seen a lot of the answers about pivoting and other solutions for transforming a 1:M relationship from many rows to many columns, but I have not seen one that addresses my specific scenario. I'm using SQL Server 2014.

I have two tables: Attendee and AttendeeChild.  Here are the relevant columns in each:

### Attendee

Id

### AttendeeChild

Id
AttendeeId
Age
Name
Gender

An Attendee can have any number of "child" rows. For each attendee, I want to flatten the AttendeeChild rows into columns so the the output looks like this for AttendeeId = 1;

```
AttendeeId Child1Age Child1Name Child1Gender Child2Age Child2Name Child2Gender
---------- --------- ---------- ------------ --------- ---------- ------------
1          10        Sam        Boy          9         Sally      Girl
```

The set of child related attributes should continue to expand the number of columns for each AttendeeChild row and the column header should keep the pattern "Child{#}{Attribute}" where {#} is an incrementing counter of the next child row from AttendeeChild and {Attribute} is either "Name", "Age" or "Gender".

I hope this is enough information to convey the issue.

Comment: Google:  "SQL Server dynamic pivot".

Comment: I have seen the dynamic examples, but from what I can see, they don't allow you to specify a column header value that is different from the value in the rows being pivoted.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @runninggeek ok I will show you an example

Comment: I suggest you find an example that doesn't do quite what you want and have a try. Then you can post a specific question with some code (which is generally the minimum effort required here)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid duly noted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another Option is to use some XML to convert the data to a EAV Structure (Entity Attribute Value)

This approach is very dynamic, and will generate the appropriate number of "groups" in the proper order.

```
Declare @AttendeeChild table (Id int,AttendeeId int,Age Int,Name varchar(50),Gender varchar(25))
Insert Into @AttendeeChild values
(1,1,10,'Sam','Boy'),
(2,1,9,'Sally','Girl'),
(2,2,9,'Sue','Boy')

-- Convert Data to EAV Structure'ish
Declare @XML xml = (Select *,GrpSeq=Row_Number() over (Partition By AttendeeId Order By Age Desc) from @AttendeeChild for XML RAW)
Select AttendeeId = r.value('@AttendeeId','int')
      ,GrpSeq     = r.value('@GrpSeq','int')
      ,ColSeq     = Row_Number() over (Partition By r.value('@AttendeeId','int') Order By (Select NULL))
      --,Item     = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Element    = 'Child'+r.value('@GrpSeq','varchar(10)')+attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
      ,Value      = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
 Into  #Temp
 From  @XML.nodes('/row') as A(r)
 Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','AttendeeId','GrpSeq')

-- Get Cols in correct Order
Declare @Cols varchar(max) = Stuff((Select ',' + QuoteName(Element) 
                                     From  (Select Distinct Top 100 Percent  ColSeq,Element From #Temp Order By ColSeq ) A
                                     For XML Path(''), Type
                                    ).value('.', 'varchar(max)'),1,1,'')

-- Execute Dynamic Pivot
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From (Select AttendeeId,Element,Value From #Temp) T
 Pivot (
        max(Value)
        For [Element] in (' + @Cols + ')
       ) P '

Exec(@SQL)
```

Returns

[image]

Comment: This is great!  There is so much going on here.  One specific question I have is the line:

Comment: @runninggeek which line?

Comment: Sorry - hit enter too soon - the line: Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr).  I have read and tried to understand the "Cross Apply" statement, but it's not computing.  Can you help me decipher what this is doing?  Thanks again for the awesome solution!

Comment: @runninggeek The Cross Apply converts the XML into 1 row per AttendeeID per Field Name (1 to many).  Select * from #Temp so you be better visualize what the first query is doing.

Comment: @runninggeek Once Temp is generated, we then can create the required columns.  These columns are then incorporated into the final dynamic pivot.

Comment: @runninggeek Added a second answer which has a clean/clear sample of the EAV approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as a template in making your dynamic SQL:

```
WITH ChildNumbered AS
(
   SELECT
      AttendeeID,
      Age,
      Name,
      Gender,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AttendeeID ORDER BY ID) AS RN
)
SELECT 
  A.ID as AttendeeId,
  C1.Age AS Child1Age, C1.Name AS Child1Name, C1.Gender AS Child1Gender,
  C2.Age AS Child2Age, C2.Name AS Child2Name, C2.Gender AS Child2Gender,
  -- ...
  CX.Age AS ChildXAge, CX.Name AS ChildXName, CX.Gender AS ChildXGender,
  CY.Age AS ChildYAge, CY.Name AS ChildYName, CY.Gender AS ChildYGender,
  CZ.Age AS ChildZAge, CZ.Name AS ChildZName, CZ.Gender AS ChildZGender
FROM Attendee AS A
LEFT JOIN ChildNumbered AS C1 ON A.ID = C1.AttendeeID AND C1.RN = 1
LEFT JOIN ChildNumbered AS C2 ON A.ID = C2.AttendeeID AND C2.RN = 2
-- ...
LEFT JOIN ChildNumbered AS CX ON A.ID = CX.AttendeeID AND CX.RN = X
LEFT JOIN ChildNumbered AS CY ON A.ID = CY.AttendeeID AND CY.RN = Y
LEFT JOIN ChildNumbered AS CZ ON A.ID = CZ.AttendeeID AND CZ.RN = Z
```